# How do I get the value of multiple inputs and assign the values to different form controls?

Tags: jquery, html

I have three HTML select boxes (Single selection), and an anchor.

The user selects their 3 options, then presses a button to confirm their selection. Once clicked the three values are added to a div inside individual span tags, and are also added to a hidden inputs value field for form submission.

The issue I'm having is, how do I assign multiple jQuery variables to an inputs "value="" " field?

I have tried:

```
$('#values').val('+myvar1+myvar2+myvar3');
```

As well as several other combinations, however there are no errors, the input is blank.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dxw9v8k/)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please learn JavaScript, before trying jQuery.

Comment: @timmyRS In this instance I would prefer to use jQuery and ask if I am unable to solve the issue myself

Comment: I always prefer jQuery, because it's better, but what made you think that `+myvar1+myvar2+myvar3` would even remotely work? And did you even define them? It's clear to see that you don't even know JavaScript, because learning JavaScript before jQuery is so much more practical, when it comes to stupid occasions like this one.

Comment: Of course I defined them, I needed to know the syntax for ".val(""+select1+select2+select3);" - If there is an issue with me asking this specific question, on a Q&A site, please contact a moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of bugs in the code. However I fixed it. Always try to `right click and inspect`on your browser to see the console whether there are any errors.

1. You had used id="myval1" in `<select>` element, but accessed them as $('.myval1') which is the selector for a css class called "myval1".
2. Same case applies to the selected option selectors you had used.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dxw9v8k/)

HTML

```
<div>
  <select id="myval1">
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="myval2">
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="myval3">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="action"><a href="#">+ Add</a></p>
<div class="values">
Spans will be here
This will be hidden
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.action').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var select1 = $( "#myval1" ).val();
            var select1text = $("#myval1 option:selected").text();
            var select2 = $( "#myval2" ).val();
            var select2text = $("#myval2 option:selected").text();
            var select3 = $( "#myval3" ).val();
            var select3text = $("#myval3 option:selected").text();
            $('.values').append('<span>'+select1text+ '</span>');
            $('.values').append('<span>'+select2text+ '</span>');
            $('.values').append('<span>'+select3text+ '</span>');
            $('.values').append('<input name="opentimes" id="open-time" />');
            $('#open-time').val(""+select1+select2+select3);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be this solution can help you with your problem. Go with below mentioned link.

[JSfiidle link](https://jsfiddle.net/5dxw9v8k/8/)

HTML Code

```
<div>
    <select id="myval1">
        <option value="0">Zero</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select id="myval2">
        <option value="0">Zero</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select id="myval3">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<p class="action"><a href="#">+ Add</a>
</p>
<div class="values">
    Spans will be here This will be hidden
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code

```
$('.action').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var select1 = $("#myval1 option:selected").val();
        var select1_text_1 = $("#myval1 option:selected").text();
        var select2 = $("#myval2 option:selected").val();
        var select1_text_2 = $("#myval2 option:selected").text();
        var select3 = $("#myval3 option:selected").val();
        var select1_text_3 = $("#myval3 option:selected").text();
var allVal = (parseInt(select1)+parseInt(select2)+parseInt(select3));
        $('.values').append('<span>'+select1_text_1+ '</span>');
        $('.values').append('<span>'+select1_text_2+ '</span>');
        $('.values').append('<span>'+select1_text_3+ '</span>');
        $('.values').append('<input name="opentimes" id="open-time" />');
        $('#open-time').val(allVal);
    });
```